# How to target all input text and password value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I'm trying to figure out how to target every input(text and password) field on all forms on the page document to remove the default value when on focus with this single script:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    Input = $('input');
    default_value = Input.val();

    $('input').focus(function() 
    {
        if($(this).val() == default_value)
        {
            $(this).val("");
        }
    }).blur(function()
    {
        if($(this).val().length == 0)
        {
            $(this).val(default_value);
        }
    });
});
```

It works only on the first input text element in the first form on my page, but nothing on the rest. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `val` only returns the value of the first selected element, instead of storing the values, you can use `defaultValue` property of the [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement) object.

```
$('input[type=text], input[type=password]').focus(function() {
   if (this.value === this.defaultValue) $(this).val("");
}).blur(function(){
   if (this.value.length === 0) this.value = this.defaultValue;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MscgZ/

Comment: Can I ask one more thing. How can I add function to this script to disable the submit button if the fields left in default value or have not been filled out?

Comment: @netizen0911 You are welcome, of course, you should listen to submit event of the `form` element, if the values are `defualtValue`s then prevent the submission using `return false`.

Answer (score 1):

Get all the input type text value:

```
$("input:text").each(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Get all input type password value:

```
$("input:password").each(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Not exactly! This is not the preferred way of selecting based on type, as it can't take advantage of querySelectorAll.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.