# jquery selector type text or password

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I select input type text OR password.

```
jQuery('input[type="text"]')
```

This selects the `text` type. How do I select the `password` type also?

Comment: and [How to target all input text and password value?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15671533/218196)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify multiple selectors using commas like this:

```
jQuery('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you can assign some Ids to your input and password fields or this will select any/all inputs in your page.
The selection would be same as p.p.w.g suggested:

```
$('#inputid', '#inputpwdid')
```